# Editing values in multiple json files

Tags: python, json, bash, console

I have a folder with let's assume 100 .json files.

In each of them, I have a repeating fragment **"f.discardLinkURLAnchors": true**, which I would like to replace with **"f.discardLinkURLAnchors": false**,

Sample file fragment:

```
   "f.defaultCharSet" : "UTF-8",
   "f.defaultMIMEType" : "application/octet-stream",
   "f.discardLinkURLAnchors" : true,
   "f.discardLinkURLQueries" : false,
```

The change method can be any (Python script, bash console). What matters is that the files are overwritten in the specified location and that the operation is performed on all files in the specified location.

Do you have any ideas? I've looked for hints in various articles, but it's usually about a different effect

Answer (score 1):

a less robust way with `sed` inplace editing, assumes properties are on separate lines.

```
for file in path/to/*.json; do
     sed -i '/"f.discardLinkURLAnchors"/s/true/false/' "$f"; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell, using `jq` and [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) (From the `moreutils` package) to do all the work:

```sh
for file in path/to/*.json; do
    jq '.properties."f.discardLinkURLAnchors" = false' "$file" | sponge "$file"
done
```

Using a JSON-aware tool for working with JSON files, not things like regular expressions, will make life *much* easier. And `sponge` is handy for cases like this where you want to save changes to the same file as the source but your other tools don't have an in-place edit mode.